# google app engine maximum number of values in all indexes for an entity = 5000

Tags: google-app-engine

I am considering using gae to host a web app but I am concerned about this limit "maximum number of values in all indexes for an entity = 5000".  Does this not effectively mean that the maximum entries for a single entity is 5000 (or less for more indexes).

The application I want to host is a simple job managament app and each job would be an entity.  The jobs can be searched/sorted using different properties (eg: Job Status, Due Date, Assigned To Person etc..) so I would need a few indexes for these queries. The current app easily does 50-60 jobs per day which means I would hit the 5000 limit in no time, probably less than 2 months.  Am I reading it right?  This limit seems very small for an engine that is design to be highly scalable.

Any information or advice on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're misinterpreting this value -- it relates to a limit on the index entries that are built for a single given entity, not over all the entities of a given Kind (like 'Job').  There's a discussion of index write costs [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities.html#Understanding_Write_Costs) that might be useful.

It is rare to hit this limit, unless you have '[exploding indexes](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries.html#Big_Entities_and_Exploding_Indexes)'.  (See [this article](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/indexselection.html) for one way to avoid such exploding indexes if that comes up-- but it doesn't sound like it will be an issue for your current design).

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful and makes complete sense.  I was confusing Entity with Kind and I suspect this stems back to my database ER diagraming days where an Entity represents a table.